# How to map a column of item lists to grouped category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

thank you in advance for you any input!

I am trying to map a column of lists in a dataframe to a grouped category.

More specifically, my column of lists would look like:

```
List            
"item1|item2"
"item3|item2"
"item1|item3"
```

Separately I have another grouped category dataframe:

```
Category    Item
C1          item1
C1          item3
C2          item2
C2          item4
```

I would like to create a new columns in the original dataframe (List) such that it becomes as follows:

```
List             Categories   C1    C2    C3   C4       
"item1|item2"    C1           TRUE
"item3|item2"    C1, C2       TRUE  TRUE
"item1|item3"    C1, C2       TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: item1|item2 should it be C1,C2 and item1|item3 to C1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Categories']=df['List'].replace(df1.set_index('Item').T.to_dict('r')[0],regex=True)

df=pd.concat([df,df.Categories.str.get_dummies('|').eq(1)],axis=1).replace({False:''})

df.Categories=df.Categories.str.split('|').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))
df
Out[194]: 
          List Categories    C1    C2
0  item1|item2      C1,C2  True  True
1  item3|item2      C1,C2  True  True
2  item1|item3         C1  True
```

PS: If you want to adding those `None` columns

```
mis=['C3','C4']
d = dict.fromkeys(mis, '')
df.assign(**d)
```

Comment: are you sure about the result?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ haha , overlook , Let me verify with op

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I wont get a chance to test until tomorrow - will let you know!